# Remote Desktop settings not being applied for user

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

We have a number of Win 2003 servers for which we have Remote Desktop enabled.  Each user has their profile edited so that they can only connect for 2 hours maximum and have 30 minutes idle time, after which they are disconnected and the session closed.  On one server however, the administrator account does not have the maximum session limit working.  We can stay connected for days if we want.  Originally this was how it was setup, and we later changed the profile for all users so that there are limits.  We have rebooted the server a couple of times since, and the Management Console shows the limits.  If we are idle for too long we are disconnected.
Other users are having all the limits observed.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the group policies if you have conflicting configurations.
Also have a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=940122

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Resultant Set of Policy (RSoP) snap-in](https://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/expert/rsop.mspx) useful in resolving your issue. Essentially it allows you to check policies in effect for a given user or computer in Active Directory environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am getting the question right but here goes.  So you are saying that at one time this server was set up with no limits on terminal sessions, but now you set the limits and all users that connect to this server have the limits applied to their session?

And the problem is that the administrator account is not having the limits applied?

If that is the case it could be Remote Desktop for Administration in Windows Server 2003.

I could be way off base here, I am just not understanding what you are asking.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814590